# React-Select not working inside Sweetalert2

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-select, sweetalert2, sweetalert2-react-content

I am trying to use a React-Select component inside Sweetalert2, but it throws an error on the console when the sweetalert pops on the screen. Attached image contains the error description

Here's my code

```
import Select from 'react-select'
import Swal, { SweetAlertResult } from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';

// Select Component
function MySelect ({ options }) {
    return <Select options={options} />
}

// Main Component
function Main() {    
    // Sweetalert initialization
    const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);

    const openPopup = () => {
        MySwal.fire({
            title: 'Create Room',
            html: (
                <form>
                    <div className="mb-2">
                        <MySelect options={options} />
                    </div>
                </form>
            ),
        }).then((result) => { // handle result})
    }

    return <button onClick={openPopup}>Open SweetAlert</button>
}
```

[image]

Thanks in anticipation!

Based on the error reported on the console, I tried following things

1. Changed the version of react-select
2. Tried passing a ref from parent component

Expectation: See a React-Select dropdown in Sweetalert

Result: Empty Sweetalert with no react-select dropdown
[image]